# tRAS definition for DDR memory

Tags: fpga, verilog, memory, ddr, ddr3

In Figure 3 of https://www.systemverilog.io/understanding-ddr4-timing-parameters#refresh , why `tRAS` is defined as the max timing between two REFRESH commands ? This seems contradicts with Micron document.

[image: tRAS definition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tRAS specifies the minimum and maximum window that a row can be ACTIVATEd for access.  The maximum value is bounded by the limitations imposed by refresh.

Every row in the DRAM needs to be refreshed periodically.  tREFI specifies the average interval between refresh operations (each operation refreshes one row).  All rows need to be refreshed within some specified time (which is usually temperature dependent - hotter operation requires more frequent refresh to guarantee data integrity).  This time might be 64ms for commercial temp range.  Meaning, typically, that 8192 refresh operations need to occur within 64ms.

The datasheet allows you to defer a scheduled refresh up to 9 x tREFI (this can be helpful for performance, since you can keep accessing that row during that interval (instead of incurring the overhead of shutting down and re-opening the row).  The timing parameters in the datasheet are very conservative.  Meaning, if you don't violate them, data will never be corrupted.  Overclockers take advantage of the conservative specmanship and violate these parameters, eating into the margin up until the point that it breaks, and then back off to their own level of comfort.

If the refresh operation is deferred, the controller needs to make up for that lost time somehow, such that the average refresh interval does not exceed tREFI. This can be done by issuing more refresh commands than necessary during idle times, but when things get busy, the controller will absolutely preempt access to keep refresh on track.

For DDR3, I think JEDEC specifies the amount of time debt as follows:  controller must issue 8 refresh commands in 8*tREFI time window.  In the limit, one could wait almost 8 full tREFIs, and then issue 8 refreshes in a row.  It is similar in DDR4, although I think there are some new refresh features available there.

Comment: but Micron document defines `tRAS` as the timing between `ACTIVATE` command and `PRECHARGE` command.

Comment: That is true. PRECHARGE is the complement to ACTIVATE.  Meaning, you open a row with ACTIVATE and close it with PRECHARGE.  This is what I was referring to in the first sentence above.  It is necessary to close any open rows before issuing a refresh command.  PRECHARGE command can close either one open bank or all open banks (each of which could have at most one row activated).

Comment: I understand that `tRC = tRAS + tRP`, why the [tRC mentioned that no PRECHARGE is allowed in between ?](https://i.imgur.com/MD9C8Of.png)

Comment: Can I ask where that text is from?  The text that says "no precharge in-between", I mean.

Comment: See https://www.mindshare.com/files/resources/MindShare_DRAM_QRG.pdf#page=2

Comment: I suspect there is a misunderstanding there (I mean the mindshare doc is wrong, or they meant something else).  tRC applies to successive ACTIVATES to the same bank.  So, by definition, there is a PRECHARGE between the two ACTIVATES.  Similarly, the open bank must be closed to issue a REFRESH, so there is a PRECHARGE there too.  The timing numbers add up.

Comment: your reply just above only applies for non-consecutive ACTIVATE command.  I suppose mindshare document considers the case for multiple **consecutive** ACTIVATE commands.

Comment: by the way, how shall I understand Figure 4 of https://www.systemverilog.io/understanding-ddr4-timing-parameters#refresh ?

Comment: Figure 4 simply illustrates one way to make up for deferred refresh cycles.  In this figure, we can see the maximum allowed gap in the refresh intervals (of 9xtREFI).  At some point the 8 missing refresh commands need to be made up so that the average tREFI is maintained.  In this example, the 8 refresh commands are issued in one tREFI period.  It can be done other ways, issuing refresh commands slightly faster for a while.

Comment: must all 8 REF-commands be executed inside a single tREFI ?

Comment: No.  It would be valid to add 1 extra to each tREFI for 8 cycles, or any other arrangement such that all pages are refreshed within 64ms.  However, for performance reasons, it makes sense to make up the deficit all at once while the DRAM is idle if the opportunity presents itself.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **add 1 extra** ?

Comment: I mean issue 2 REF commands in the time where there would normally be only 1.  This is just one example of a way to make up for missed refresh cycles.  The REF timing flexibility allows the implementer of the memory controller can choose how they go about meeting the refresh requirements.  A REF command can be deferred for performance reasons, if the controller is in the middle of a burst read, for example.  At some point, that missed REF needs to be executed without violating the 64ms overall refresh cycle.

Comment: if the (postponed) refresh scheduler logic is correct, why would there be even a possibility of `1 missed refresh cycle` ?

Comment: OK, so the reason the controller falls behind on REF cycles is to improve performance.  If the controller is rigid and performs REFs on a strict schedule, it will have to preempt some data accesses.  This causes a delay in data transfer, and hence and reduction in performance.  So, the game is to defer refresh cycles when the memory is active, and make them up when it is idle.